# oracle sql trigger calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, calculation

I have something calculation problem. 
my logic is Sum all the quantity of the stock that is Buy which the code is 'B'

also, sum all the quantity of the stock that is sell which the code is 'S'.

In order to know the person owns the quantity of the stock to sell.
is the 'B'quantity -'S' quantity should come out the number of stock the is owns by the person.

```
select sum(quantity) 
into V_quantityS
from transaction
where :new.portfolio_number = portfolio_number
and :new.stock_code = stock_code
and buy_sell='S'
;

select sum(quantity)
into V_quantityB
from transaction
where :new.portfolio_number = portfolio_number
and :new.stock_code = stock_code
and buy_sell='B'
;

if (V_quantityB-V_quantityS) < :new.quantity then

  Raise_Application_Error(-20020, 'The Investor have not enough stock to sell ');

ELSE 
  update Account 
  set Account_Balance = Account_Balance+(:new.quantity* :new.Price_per_share)
  where V_account_number = Account_Number;
```

example total is own 10 in IBM

```
ID=500, Stock_code ='IBM' code 'B' Quantity = '20' 
ID=500, Stock_code ='IBM' code 'S' Quantity = '10'
```

but I can insert

```
INSERT INTO Transaction 
(Portfolio_Number, Transaction_Date, Stock_Code, Exchange_Code, Broker_Number, Buy_Sell, Quantity, Price_Per_Share)
values
    (500, To_Date('12-Feb-2020 16:41:00', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MEZ', 'TSX', 4, 'S', 11000, 25.55 );
```

IF insert the second time which is

```
INSERT INTO Transaction 
(Portfolio_Number, Transaction_Date, Stock_Code, Exchange_Code, Broker_Number, Buy_Sell, Quantity, Price_Per_Share)
values
    (500, To_Date('12-Feb-2020 16:41:00', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MEZ', 'TSX', 4, 'S', 1, 25.55 );
```

no matter how many stocks are. it will be inserted. after that, then I can't insert which will raise the error

Comment: Please try to make your text moer simple. For example: I can insert this: ...code... but this couese the error: ...code... Also please show us the error that you get ? Is it the message "The Investor have not enough stock to sell "?

Comment: 1) You can make one select instead of two: `select sum(case buy_sell when 'B' then quantity else -quantity end) into vQuantity`. 2) You should not select from the same table on which row-level trigger operates, it will cause `mutating table` error. 3) Your trigger works ( [simple dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b2d084df6c5ae55507137b1b456a2f9) ) for single inserts and throws errors as expected. There must be something which you did not show us.